# Пересекаются ли параллелепипед и прямоугольник в пространстве

Tags: python, геометрия, коллизии

Думаю над алгоритмом, мне примерно по пунктам понятно, что делать, но как подобраться к решению, местами не ясно.

Суть такая:
Есть задача перенести объект (скажем, коробка) из точки A в точки B1, B2, B3 и тд. На пути есть некая защищённая зона, в которую объект не должен врезаться. В зависимости от точки Bn объект либо заденет, либо нет.

Найти пересечение двух отрезков, отрезка и плоскости даже - тут моих знаний в аналитической геометрии вроде хватает, а вот с параллелепипедом ступорюсь и не знаю куда двигаться.

P.S. Спокойно читаю python, C++, JS, русский и английский. Приму помощь на любом из этих языков. Спасибо!

Comment: Что-то незаметно, что вы пытались решить задачу самостоятельно. Ваше "помочь" означает "решить за меня".

Comment: Вероятно, вам стоит указать, что примерно вам понятно и перечислить непонятные места. Пока это может выглядеть либо как "сделайте за меня, я правда почти всё знаю", либо как "угадайте господа телепаты, что именно мне непонятно". Извините, но ни то, ни то - не для stackoverflow. Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для каждой вершины параллелепипеда у вас есть отрезок, который соединяет старое местоположение и новое.
2. Как вы написали в вопросе, вы уже умеете найти пересечение отрезка и плоскости. Для каждого из отрезков из пункта 1 вам нужно найти его пересечение с плоскостью, в которое лежит прямоугольник запрещённой зоны.
3. Если такое пересечение есть, то вы получаете на этой плоскости многоугольник. И вам остаётся только проверить, есть ли пересечения у этого многоугольника с запрещённым прямоугольником.